# undefined method `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x6b04720>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Im getting the above titled error after i try to update my painting model .

Heres my painting controller

```
def update 
    @painting = Painting.find(params[:id])
    if @painting.update_attributes(params[:painting])
        redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @painting
    else
        @paintings = Painting.find(:all)
        render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
```

Heres my model

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :gallery_id, :name, :image, :avatar
    belongs_to :gallery
    mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
    has_attached_file :avatar, :default_url =>     "/images/:style/missing.png"
      # , :url  => "/assets/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
    validates_presence_of :name

end
```

Heres my painting form partial

```
<%= form_for([@gallery,@painting], :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <!-- <#%= form_for @painting, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %> -->

      <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </p>
      <p><%= f.file_field :avatar %></p>

      <p><%= f.submit %></p>
    <% end %>
```

A painting belongs to a gallery i.e gallery contains painting.
P.S I'm using carrierwave as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok It was an issue of mountuploader . I had to comment it out and it worked .Phew :-)**

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :gallery_id, :name, :image, :avatar
    belongs_to :gallery
    # mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
    has_attached_file :avatar, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png", :url  => "/assets/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
    validates_presence_of :name
    # skip_callback :save, :after, :remove_previously_stored_avatar

end
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just disable CarrierWave altogether?

Comment: @fatuhoku I suppose it would. I was working on two gems at same time , removed mount_uploader for my project

Comment: In my case, it was due to a find_by_sql that did not retrieve all fields.